# Join data frames without creating duplicate rows while concatenating unique entries under one column

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I'm trying to merge two data frames together which are related to each other via a specific variable named `patient`. The second data frame has multiple entries for the same patient column. I don't want to create duplicate patient entries upon merging, but I want to retain unique information in the second data frame by concatenating the values under one column.

I tried manually concatenating certain variables using `group_by` which works. I have several variables, however, and manually specifying all of them is not feasible

I can also concatenate every variable in the data frame by using `dplyr` as seen below. The problem in the second case is that duplicate values are also concatenated making the data frame unnecessarily big and difficult to deal with. Please see the reprex below.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df1 <- data.frame(patient=c("a", "b", "c"), 
                  var1 = 1:3, 
                  var2=11:13)

df1
#>   patient var1 var2
#> 1       a    1   11
#> 2       b    2   12
#> 3       c    3   13



df2 <- data.frame(patient=c("a","a", "b", "b", "c", "c" ), 
                  treatment=  rep(c("drug1", "drug2"), 3), 
                  time= rep(c("time1", "time2"), 3),
                  var3= "constant")

df2
#>   patient treatment  time     var3
#> 1       a     drug1 time1 constant
#> 2       a     drug2 time2 constant
#> 3       b     drug1 time1 constant
#> 4       b     drug2 time2 constant
#> 5       c     drug1 time1 constant
#> 6       c     drug2 time2 constant


df_merged <- left_join(df1, df2)
#> Joining, by = "patient"

# Don't want duplicates like this
df_merged
#>   patient var1 var2 treatment  time     var3
#> 1       a    1   11     drug1 time1 constant
#> 2       a    1   11     drug2 time2 constant
#> 3       b    2   12     drug1 time1 constant
#> 4       b    2   12     drug2 time2 constant
#> 5       c    3   13     drug1 time1 constant
#> 6       c    3   13     drug2 time2 constant



df_merged2 <- df_merged %>%
  group_by(patient) %>%
  mutate(treatment = paste(treatment, collapse = "_"),
         time=paste(time, collapse = "_")) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(patient))

# I can manually edit a few variables like this
df_merged2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#> # Groups:   patient [3]
#>   patient  var1  var2 treatment   time        var3    
#>   <fct>   <int> <int> <chr>       <chr>       <fct>   
#> 1 a           1    11 drug1_drug2 time1_time2 constant
#> 2 b           2    12 drug1_drug2 time1_time2 constant
#> 3 c           3    13 drug1_drug2 time1_time2 constant


df_merged3 <- df_merged %>%
  group_by(patient) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), .funs = ~paste(., collapse ="_")) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(patient))


# I have many variables I can't specify manually
# I can create this merged data frame, but I don't want to 
# concatenate duplicated values such as var1, var2, and var3
df_merged3
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#> # Groups:   patient [3]
#>   patient var1  var2  treatment   time        var3             
#>   <fct>   <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>            
#> 1 a       1_1   11_11 drug1_drug2 time1_time2 constant_constant
#> 2 b       2_2   12_12 drug1_drug2 time1_time2 constant_constant
#> 3 c       3_3   13_13 drug1_drug2 time1_time2 constant_constant
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I'd like to see if there is a way of concatenating variables containing only unique values to retain information from the second data frame without duplicating the rows in the `df_merged`.

I would be happy to hear if you have recommendations other than `dplyr`. A `data.table` solution may also be suitable for me as well, since my real data frames are quite large.

Thanks!

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! Please write this as an answer so I can give you the upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `summarise_at` and `unique`

```
library(dplyr)
df_merged %>%
          group_by(patient) %>%
          summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), .funs = ~paste(unique(.), collapse ="_"))
```

Or we can do the merge/joint directly instead of adding/altering the Global Env with an intermediate dataframe.

```
left_join(df1, 
          df2 %>% group_by(patient) %>% 
                  summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), .funs = ~paste(unique(.), collapse ="_")) %>% 
                  ungroup()
         )

Joining, by = "patient"
  patient var1 var2   treatment        time     var3
1       a    1   11 drug1_drug2 time1_time2 constant
2       b    2   12 drug1_drug2 time1_time2 constant
3       c    3   13 drug1_drug2 time1_time2 constant
```

## Update

```
#Here a toy example to experiment with, uncomment browser to see how it works inside Reduce, 
#also see ?Reduce for more info 
paste_mod <- function(x) Reduce(function(u, v){
u <- ifelse(!grepl('_',u) & is.na(u),'.',u)
v <- ifelse(is.na(v),'.',v)
if(v=='.' | !grepl(v,u)) paste0(u,'_',v) else u
}, x)

paste_mod(c("drug1",NA,NA,"drug2","drug1","drug2"))
[1] "drug1_._._drug2"
paste_mod(c(NA,NA,"drug2","drug1","drug2"))
[1] "._._drug2_drug1"

#replace NA with . then apply Reduce
df2 %>% 
       mutate_if(is.factor,as.character) %>% mutate_all(~replace(.,is.na(.),'.')) %>% 
       group_by(patient) %>% 
       summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), .funs = ~Reduce(function(u, v) if(v=='.' | !grepl(v,u)) paste0(u,'_',v) else u, .)) %>% 
       ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  patient treatment       time        var3    
  <chr>   <chr>           <chr>       <chr>   
1 a       drug1_._._drug2 time1_time2 constant
2 c       drug1_drug2     time1_time2 constant
```

New `df2` for testing the updated solution

```
df2 <- structure(list(patient = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"c"), class = "factor"), treatment = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("drug1", "drug2"), class = "factor"), 
    time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("time1", 
    "time2"), class = "factor"), var3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "constant")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Is there a way of adding a symbol when there are `NA`s in the duplicate rows to retain information regarding missingness? So that, if the 4 data points (e.g. `"drug1, NA, NA, drug2"`) are concatenated together, I can still track the entries as `drug1_._._drug2`.

Comment: I'd like to preserve the order

Comment: Thank you. I can't wrap my mind around the relationship between the `v` and `u` in the context of `Reduce` function though. Can you please elaborate on this? Also another point that would be helpful is the following: My initial goal was avoiding pasting duplicate values (where all the duplicates are the same). However if there is a case, say, where a patient is treated with `"drug1, NA, NA, drug2, NA, drug1, drug2"` in this particular order, I'd like to be able to see this in the concatenated output as `"drug1_._._drug2_._drug1_drug2"`. Is this possible?

Comment: I think I figured something out by the help of Google. This can do what I want for non repetitive duplicates, but it also pastes the fully repetitive duplicates: 

Mock data ```df2 <- data.frame(patient=rep(c("a", "b","c", each=4), 
                  treatment=  rep(c("drug1", NA, "drug1", "drug2"), 3), 
                  time= rep(c("time1", "time2"), 6),
                  var3= "constant")```
Changing the `Reduce` code as follows fixed one thing while breaking another.
```Reduce(function(u, v){
  # browser()
  v <- ifelse(is.na(v),'.',v)
  paste0(u,'_',v)
}
```

Comment: In the 1st round; `u` takes the 1s element while `v` takes the 2nd element then `paste` and assign them into `u`. In the 2nd round; `v` takes the 3rd element and `paste`'ed with `u` and so on, for that we always check `v` if its NA or has been in `u` before, if that the case we skip i.e. don't `paste` u and `v` and just return `u`. See [this tutorial](https://blog.zhaw.ch/datascience/r-reduce-applys-lesser-known-brother/) for better understanding of `Reduce`. Now I notice we didn't check `u` for NA in the 1st round, so see my update.

Comment: I can't understand `pastes the fully repetitive duplicate`, Do you mean in case of "drug1,drug1, NA, NA, drug2, NA, drug1, drug2", you will need "drug1_._._drug2_._drug1_drug2"

Comment: If so, we can check if `v` is in the last element of `u` by using `tail`, `paste_mod <- function(x) Reduce(function(u, v){#browser()
    u <- ifelse(!grepl('_',u) & is.na(u),'.',u)
    v <- ifelse(is.na(v),'.',v)
    if(v=='.' | !grepl(v,tail(strsplit(u,'_')[[1]],n=1))) paste0(u,'_',v) else u
},x);paste_mod(c("drug1","drug2",NA,NA,"drug1","drug2","drug2","drug2"))`

Comment: What I meant was I want to convert `"drug1, NA, NA, drug2, drug1, drug2"` to `"drug1_._._drug2_drug1_drug2"`, but I want to prevent `"drug1, drug1, drug1"` from becoming `"drug1_drug1_drug1"`. Thanks so much the help, I appreciate it!